# Pushing a DIV down a page everytime a new ID is assigned to it

Tags: php, css

I have `DIV` on this forum page which has a variable ID. The ID is generated every time a new post is made. I would like to have this `DIV` push down the page a certain amount everytime a new ID is generated. Is there a way to do this?

I am using `PHP` to assign the ID to the `DIV`. Here is the code to assign ID to DIV whic works. But I still down know how to push this DIV down the page everytime a new ID is assigned. Any help will be highly appreciated...

```
<!-- PHP --> $post_id = $_SESSION['POST_ID']; <!-- ENDPHP -->

<div id="<!-- PHP -->echo p,$post_id; <!-- ENDPHP -->" style="position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: "Here is the code and it works." - congratulations. And what do you want from us?

Comment: sorry I meant the php code to assign the ID to the DIV works. But I still don't know how I can push this DIV down the page everytime a new ID is created.

Comment: I believe that you are experiencing problems with absolute style stacking all the posts on top of each other, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "ajax" to feed the entry in your php page, then just add prepend function in jQuery to add the current content in the top.

```
$("#maincontentid").prepend("HTML");
```

or if you are using page refresh, the try to fetch the data using descending order in your SQL query.